# ASP Webpage Wont load

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, xampp

First off I just want to say I've searched everywhere and cant find a solution. I am running VS 2010 and I can not get a web page to load. When I go to the design page is vs I can see stuff on the page but nothing in the browser. I tried using IIS and tried using xampp.

The "URL" trying to be ran is: localhost:60479/WebShopperGridMultipleImage/Default.aspx

Response: The connection has timed out. The server at www.localhost.com is taking too long to respond.

I am very new to aspx and running from a local host. My teacher suggested running xampp and I can't get anything to load. Not sure where to go from here.

Note: I am running windows 7. I am running the file from the htdocs folder inside xampp. I tried using IIS while in the wwwroot folder and tried running the aspnet_regiis -i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the url should be like this: 
http://localhost/WebShopperGridMultipleImage/Default.aspx
and ur iis set a website with the nama "WebShopperGridMultipleImage" and the default page set it as Default.aspx

Comment: That is what i had while using IIS and it redirects me to localhost.com with the error "The connection was reset"

Comment: at ur IIS.. right click the file.. click browse.. can the page be display?

or u go to  c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
open with notepad. check if there is a row like this.. (if doesnt have then add it at the last row and save the file) 
127.0.0.01 localhost 
and make sure is NOT
::localhost

Comment: It was the hosts file. Not sure how that got changed. Thanks a ton!